# How to add transparency to RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I have three 3D plots which I wish I can show them in the same plot. I think transparency may help but I don't know how. Could any one help me by providing an example?

Comment: `RegionPlot[..., PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]`

Comment: I RegionPlot3D @MichaelE2

Comment: Doesn't it work for that, too?  (Just not for `ContourPlot*` functions, which use `ContourStyle`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aa = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^3 - z^2 > 0,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]]];
bb = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 2,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]];
cc = RegionPlot3D[2 (x - 1)^2 + y^2 + 2 z^2 < 4,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]];
Show[aa, bb, cc]
```

[image]